# Array equation numbering misplaced

Tags: equations

I have a couple of equations from *Autometrics* which I want numbered but for some reason, the equation numbering always goes on the line below the equation. I would want the numbering to be somewhere in the middle of the equation or next to the last line of the equation. Below is the code for one of the equations. Thanks

```
\documentclass[12pt, varwidth, border=10pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[final]{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \begin{array}{lcl}
  r_{p,t} & = &
  \begin{array}[t]{r} 
  0.0043
  \\ ^{(0.003)}
  \end{array}
  \ -\!\begin{array}[t]{r}
  0.0068
 \\ ^{(0.0019)}
 \end{array}
 D_{1}
 \ -\!\begin{array}[t]{r}
 0.0053
 \\ ^{(0.0023)}
 \end{array}
 D_{2}
 \ -\!\begin{array}[t]{r}
 0.0036
 \\ ^{(0.0021)}
 \end{array}
  D_{3}
  \ -\!\begin{array}[t]{r}
  0.00026
  \\ ^{(0.0020)}
  \end{array}
  D_{4}
  \ +\!\begin{array}[t]{r}
  0.31
  \\ ^{(0.066)}
  \end{array}
   R_{Mt}
  \\ & &
  \ +\!\begin{array}[t]{r}
 0.026
 \\ ^{(0.0016)}
 \end{array}
 \text{S}_{\text{13-Dec}}
 \ -\!\begin{array}[t]{r}
  0.026
  \\ ^{(0.0030)}
  \end{array}
  \text{S}_{\text{16-Dec}}
  \end{array} 
  \end{equation} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: please always provide a test example, the equation number is moved down if it does not fit but you have given no indication of the page width or provided a usable test file. Why are you using `array` here?

Comment: @ David Carlisle Thanks for pointing this out. I have now provided additional details. I am using an array since this is the format with which the equations are provided by the statistical software I am using. The problem comes when I edit the equations a bit for presentation purposes then the equation numbering goes on the next line below the equation.

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest a few improvements, one of which is to use `\begin{array}[t]{@{}r@{}}`. The other is to reduce the distance between the number and the accuracy; finally `split` is a lot easier.

A macro for easing input is also recommended.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{geometry}

\newcommand{\numprec}[2]{%
  \begingroup\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.5}%
  \begin{array}[t]{@{}r@{}} #1 \\ \scriptstyle (#2) \end{array}%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
  r_{p,t} &=
  \numprec{0.0043}{0.003}
 -\numprec{0.0068}{0.0019} \, D_{1}
 -\numprec{0.0053}{0.0023} \, D_{2}
 -\numprec{0.0036}{0.0021} \, D_{3}
 -\numprec{0.00026}{0.0020} \, D_{4}
 +\numprec{0.31}{0.066} \, R_{Mt}
\\
 &\qquad
 +\numprec{0.026}{0.0016} \, \mathrm{S}_{\text{13-Dec}}
 -\numprec{0.026}{0.0030} \, \mathrm{S}_{\text{16-Dec}}
\end{split}
\end{equation} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

In case the first row doesn't fit, you can move the last summand to the next line.

If you remove the `\qquad`, you get

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

If you remove the padding from the arrays with `@{}` you can use normal spacing around `=`, `-`, `+` and then I'd use an AMS multi line display rather than an outer `array`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{multline}
  r_{p,t}  = 
  \begin{array}[t]{@{}r@{}} 
  0.0043
  \\ ^{(0.003)}
  \end{array}
  -\begin{array}[t]{@{}r@{}}
  0.0068
 \\ ^{(0.0019)}
 \end{array}
 D_{1}
 -\begin{array}[t]{@{}r@{}}
 0.0053
 \\ ^{(0.0023)}
 \end{array}
 D_{2}
 -\begin{array}[t]{@{}r@{}}
 0.0036
 \\ ^{(0.0021)}
 \end{array}
  D_{3}
  -\begin{array}[t]{@{}r@{}}
  0.00026
  \\ ^{(0.0020)}
  \end{array}
  D_{4}
  +\begin{array}[t]{@{}r@{}}
  0.31
  \\ ^{(0.066)}
  \end{array}
   R_{Mt}
\\
  +\begin{array}[t]{@{}r@{}}
 0.026
 \\ ^{(0.0016)}
 \end{array}
 \text{S}_{\text{13-Dec}}
 -\begin{array}[t]{@{}r@{}}
  0.026
  \\ ^{(0.0030)}
  \end{array}
  \text{S}_{\text{16-Dec}}
  \end{multline}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I am now wondering how I can get the second line of the equation to be aligned to the equal sign in the first line as I would get in an array. Thanks

Comment: `array` is not designed for these things, the spacing is all wrong for equations and it sets the terms in text not display style, use `\begin{align*}` instead of `\begin{multilne}` if yoy want to specify an alignment and use a singe `&=` or `={}&` (depending where you want the `+`) @SamsonMukanjari